# Cannot read property getexperience of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, brightcove

Apparently no one bothered to realize that my code was from an example code from BrightCove and just brushed it off like "declared it" or that it's too vague?

```
player = brightcove.api.getExperience();
```

This line is giving me `Cannot read property 'getexperience' of undefined`
The undefined is brightcove.api which should be called in BrightCove's JS that I am linking to with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
```

I don't know how to explain more because I honestly don't know what is wrong.

[Full Code](http://pastebin.com/jLWhzC9j)

[Tutorial where this code is from](https://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/solutions/overlay-message-3.html)

Comment: Honestly no one  is going to bother to realize that your code was from an example. It's not personal. Are you getting any errors in your browser's console other than this one?

Comment: the `api` property of `brightcove` is undefined. That is why the error occurs.

Comment: No I am only getting the error that brightcove.api is undefined. When I take that out and add and external call to `http://admin.brightcove.com/js/APIModules_all.js` it tells me that player wasn't defined properly in lines after.  And its the fact that I got downvoted to oblivion and the post closed because of this one line.

Comment: The point is the error is caused due to the fact that either something isn't included properly, or isn't initialized properly. that isn't really something we can debug for you.

Comment: Okay thank you for the reply. At least I'm getting somewhere now.

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you've linked describes a player plugin. As a plugin it's designed to run in the HTML5 player's iframe. Your code in pastebin uses the script directly in the page in which the player is embedded.

You need to save the plugin code as a js file, and add the URL to that file to the Brightcove player in the player settings in Brightcove studio.

[Brightcove's plugin documentation](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/samples/adding-functionality-smart-players-using-plug-ins.html)

For what it's worth `brightcove.api.getExperience()` will be defined if you removed the `APIModules_all.js` script (and you have `<param name="includeAPI" value="true" />` *and* the player API is enabled in the player's settings). Brightcove has two versions of their player API -- that script loads the old version which does not include `brightcove.api`. Changing that still wouldn't get your code working without changing it to a plugin though - the next problem you'd run into is that `videoPlayer.overlay()` works *only* in a plugin.